# What is cufon and canvas and how to overwrite them

Tags: html, css, wordpress, canvas, cufon

In my Wordpress theme I had a hover effect on my top menu but then it suddenly stopped working and I don't know why, so I tried to inspect element to see what was going on and also tried to add a css class like this to try to get the over effect back:

```
#navigation li a:hover{color:#b0d719 !important;}
```

But it's not working, then I realized something in html... those cufon and canvas thing which I don't know what it is and also don't know how to overwrite them to accomplish this to get the hover effect back again on the navigation bar.

Here's my **[website link](http://tv.pulseframe.com)** and here's a image preview where this is happening as well

[image]

Comment: cufon is the old way to use "non safe" fonts before the @font-face. What it does is to overlap the real text with an image, so you keep the text for SEO, yet everybody see a nice font (which is an image). Cufon ALWAYS was very limited in terms of CSS, that was one of its restrictions, and it was quite insecure, so, while I don't know if this is the issue know, I'm betting the new WP version has applied a patch that, in term, made Cufon stop working. The good news is the solution is easy and better than Cufon: simply add your font with @ font-face and problem solved

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation @Fabio I just figured it out how to fix this, but still don't know why was this error happening, I've added the way how I fixed it as an answer

Comment: yes, I see it now. Either way, I highly recommend to move to font-face. It's faster, more secure, less requests to server and if you get bored you can simply change the fonts to something else in 5 seconds ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a few tests removing shorts of codes and stuff I just figured it out. I had this code above of all of those JS scripts and CSS as well in header

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// document ready equivalent
$(function(){
   // hide
   $( "#share-stuff" ).hide();

   $( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
    $( "#share-stuff" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
     // Animation complete.
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Then I removed it and the hover effect worked well, so I moved this to below of all of the Js and CSS placed in the header and it is working now, but still don't know why is this, neither what's the reason of doing that, still I would like to know

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that library, but I think that removing the following code will solve your problem:

```js
Cufon.replace('#navigation > ul > li > a', {
    textShadow: '1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
    hover: {
        color: linksColor
    }
});
```

There are some other `Cufon.replace` calls you may want to remove.

Also, if you don't want that library, you could remove

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://tv.pulseframe.com/wp-content/themes/trademark/files/js/cufon.js?ver=4.0'></script>
```

but it may break your `script.js` and `theme.js` scripts.

Comment: Well I just figured it out. I had this code above of all of those JS scripts and CSS as well in header

`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 // document ready equivalent
$(function(){
    // hide
    $( "#share-stuff" ).hide();

    $( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
      $( "#share-stuff" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
});
 </script>`

Then I moved this to below of all of it and it is working, but still don't know why